# Deny access to folders and content in it, lying in my Website folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

### In short, I don't want a user to access folders, or the data or files in it.

I searched a bit, and I came up with `deny from all`, but it is not working when I put it on ftp; but on localhost its working.

I write the below given code in my upload folder:

```
# .htaccess mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

deny from all
```

Comment: did you name the file `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Just put an index.php file in the folder with the code:

```
<?php
header("Location: ../");
?>
```

It will through the user out of that folder.